# Cannot open a tia portal v14 project

Tags: siemens, tia-portal

Hello i am trying to open a Tia Portal v14 project but it is not possible because one error appears when i try to start it.
The image shows the error and the tia portal installed.
Can someone help me to solve this?
[image]

Comment: It happends when you have another version installed, for example if you have the basic version but the project was created with the professional version